# Content Porter 2013 SP1 with Oracle

Tags: content-porter-2013, oracle

I was attempting to export from a Dev instance to a clean QA instance of 2013 SP1 with Content Porter 2013 SP1. Both instances are in matching environments concerning hardware/software and the QA blueprint matches the Dev instance.

Does anyone have a clue given the below stacktrace?

```
[Error] Tridion.ContentManager.DatabaseException: A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS.READ_PUBLICATION". ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-55714: savepoint 'READ_OLDDATA_WORKAROUND' disabled with interleaved changes across Oracle RAC instances
ORA-06512: at "TCM_OWN.EDA_PUBLICATIONS", line 1007
ORA-06512: at line 1
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.IsExistingObject(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.IsExistingObject(String uri)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.StronglyTypedFilter.ValidateLinks(Session session)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowManager.GetListProcessDefinitionsData(ProcessDefinitionsFilter& filter)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowManager.GetProcessDefinitions(ProcessDefinitionsFilter filter)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.MappingsResolver.UpdateProcessDefinitionMappings(Repository publication)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObject)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.UpdateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)
```

Comment: At a glance, it's complaining about your RAC configuration. I'd open a support ticket for this - if you haven't already - and probably double check the RAC configuration.

Comment: Hello craftyCodeMonkey, Like Nuno points out it looks like a RAC configuration or a difference between Oracle DBs. Can you maybe tell us what you try to content port, every thing at once (schema, components, templates etc) or 1 publication at the time ? (Might be some dependencie that is causing the failure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was informed by SDL support that Oracle RAC configurations of Active-Active are not supported. We switched to a stand-alone instance for the CM and the problem was solved.

Comment: Can you accept this answer please? It's nice to keep the 'resolved questions' stats up!